# Jack and Jill are standing in a room of $60$ people

Tags: probability

If I divide the room into $2$  groups of $30$, group $A$ and group $B$, what is the probability that Jack and Jill are in the same group?

What about $3$ groups?

Comment: Its not I know, this is just a question I saw online and wasnt sure how to do

Comment: Well I guess Im done part A

Comment: If we put jack in 1 group, then we are picking 29 other students to join him, and so jill has 29/59 chance

Comment: but im not sure about 3

Comment: @KracX Next time you are on this site, ensure that all you have said so far in the comments, is already part of the question when it is posted. Otherwise, people will think you re posting homework (if you don't know what to do, at least write "I don't know" or give some context like you picked it up online). This will benefit you and other users of the site. As for the first question, in case you are not getting the logic at first, try doing it with four people first, then extend to six. See the pattern and extend it to sixty. Otherwise, I am here, so please reply.

Comment: Hint.  Do you think it makes any difference if they are both in group A or group B.  There are four possibilities. Both in A.  Both in B. Jill in A jack in B.  Jill in B jack in A.  What do you think the probabilities of each of those are.

Comment: Not meaning to bug you, but I think you'd like [this chat room of mine](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art).  Based on the questions you ask, you look like you are just at the right level to fit in.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that Jack is in some group. Then, given that Jill could be any of the other $59$ people, she has $\frac {29}{59}$ chance of being with Jack. So your answer is correct.

Suppose it becomes three groups, the same logic can be applied, only that now Jill has to be one of $19$ people to be in the same group as Jack, since each group has $20$ people. So the answer is $\frac {19}{59}$ in this case.

Comment: If there are 3 groups. Let's put Jack in a group. Thus there are 59 people left. We put 20 in a group. 39 left. We put another 20 in a group. 19 left. Jill is in that 19. Thus she has a 19/59 chance. Is this correct

Comment: @KracX That is correct! Now you can see how it happens for four,five groups etc. But if the size of the groups are different i.e. if one group has 20 people, one has 30 people and one ten people, then the answer would not be so simple. You should try this question too.

Comment: Is there a way I can express this probability using combinations? I'm guessing the sample space size would be 60C30, since out of the 60 people, we are choosing 30 to put in 1 group. I'm not sure what the numerator would be though? This is for part a) (30 each)

Comment: @KracX To be honest, I tried approaching the question that way, and got a little stuck. You are right on the sample space. The favourable case is: leave Jack and Jill out, or include both of them. Leaving them out, we have to choose $30$ from $58$ people, so that makes $\binom {58}{30}$, and then the same number comes when you include both of them, so the favourable cases are just $2$  times this number.  So the answer is $2 \times \binom {58}{30} \div \binom {60}{30}  = \frac{29}{59}$, which is right!

Comment: Okay thanks for your help and suggestion in the comments directly underneath my question! appretiate it

Comment: @KracX You are very welcome.